# Is there any function in jquery that counts the time the mouse is over a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery and 
when i mouse over div A, div B appears.

What i would like to achieve is:

When the mouse is over div A **greater than 3 seconds** ( > 3s),
the div B shall appear.

Is there any function in jquery that counts the time the mouse is over a div??

Thanks, in advance

Comment: you have `mouseover`, `mouseout` events and `getTime` why would you need predefined function ?

Answer (score 6):

```
var timer;
$('#diva')
    .mouseenter(function () {
        timer = setTimeout(function () { $('#divb').show(); }, 3000);
    })
    .mouseleave(function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    });
```

Upon entering `#diva`, you start a timeout that will display `#divb` after 3 seconds. Upon leaving `#diva`, you cancel that timeout. As simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

Just assign a timeout and clear it on mouseout:

```
var interval;

$("#over").hover(function(){
    interval = window.setTimeout(function(){
        $("#b").show();
    },3000);   
},function(){
    window.clearTimeout(interval);
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/3QGpA/1/

Answer (score 0):

i don't think so..but you can achieve this by adding `setTimeOut` in your `hover` handler